# JSON response not a true string when passed to HTML template?

Tags: python, html, django, json, freebase

I'm confused by the following behavior:

Using Freebase-Python, I send a request to the Freebase API that is a query for a JSON response.  I get the response, for example:

```
  "status": "200 OK", 
  "code": "\/api\/status\/ok", 
  "result": {
    "\/common\/topic\/weblink": [
      {
        "url": "http:\/\/www.boardgamegeek.com\/boardgame\/13\/Settlers of Catan", 
        "description": "BoardGameGeek"
      }
    ], 
    "id": "\/en\/settlers_of_catan"
  }
```

Within the same RequestHandler class that I used issue the request, I can do things like,

```
print result.id 
>>> /en/settlers_of_catan
print result["/common/topic/weblink"][0].url
>>> http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13/Settlers of Catan
```

However, when I pass the result object to an HTML template, the weird behavior starts.

I can do,

```
{{ result.id }}
```

Which will render  "/en/settlers_of_catan" in the browser.  But if I try,

{{ result["/common/topic/weblink"][0].url }}

I get an error:

```
  raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Could not parse the remainder: %s" % token[upto:]
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ["/common/topic/weblink"][0].url
```

I can also just display the result:

```
{{ result }}
```

Which results in the browser:

```
{u'/common/topic/weblink': [{u'url': u'http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13/Settlers of Catan', u'description': u'BoardGameGeek'}], u'id': u'/en/settlers_of_catan'}
```

My question is, why can't I access the result in the HTML template the same way I can from the RequestHandler?

Comment: Django template language is not Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) dictionary-, list index and attribute lookups are made using a dot ('.').

For that reason it should be something like `{{ result.mylink.0.url }}`, but this will most like not work using slashes in the key!

Comment: Is there a way to escape the key?

Comment: You could try to use a custom template filter like this example: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/411/. and then get the value with `{{ result|getattr:"/common...." }}`